# How do I bypass Accept header validation in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, nancy, http-status-code-406

I have a [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy) website hosted on ASP.Net with a number of custom routes.  These routes include mappings which look like file paths (e.g. `/path/to/xml_file.xml`), but that resolve to HTML files which should display in the browser. For most files, this works correctly.  However, with XML files (and possibly other mime types), I am getting a 406.0 HTTP error from IIS 8 Express explicitly stating that

> HTTP Error 406.0 - Not Acceptable
>
> The resource cannot be displayed because the file extension is not being accepted by your browser.
>
> The request was rejected because it contained an Accept header for a MIME type that is not supported for the requested file extension.
>
> Verify the MIME settings for the file extension that was requested to make sure this MIME type is acceptable.

[image: 406 Error Page Screenshot]

Is there any web.config setting or other technique for bypassing this validation so that I don't get this error without having to rewrite the path logic?  My Google searching is failing me.  For example, I have found [this IIS forum post](http://forums.iis.net/t/1133196.aspx) linked from the [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7508583/1603383) which talks about

> map all reqests to ASP.NET and use the ASP.NET's StaticFileHandler to serve them

However, the post does not explain how to do this; nor does it seem applicable.

**Edit:** (Added error page image above)

As another tidbit, the Nancy route returns an explicit view of the form

```
return View["view_name", myModel];
```

And therefore, should bypass content negotiation.

Comment: have you checked if .xml is specific as mime type in IIS ?

Comment: @DinoMyte As specified in the comment to ourmandave's answer, I have played with different mappings in my web.config file to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not a fix or answer per se, my current work around (for anyone who might be interested) is to tweak the routes to use a trailing slash.  As an example:

```
"/path/to/xml_file.xml"   //  Still returns a 406.0 error
"/path/to/xml_file.xml/"  //  Works properly (notice the trailing slash)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the Rackspace knowledge center that shows how to change the MIME mapping for static content in the web.config file.

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

There's also this one from MS that's more in-depth.

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

They both feature this stanza from the web.config file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".extension" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".extension" mimeType="application/example" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If that's how to actually fix the 406.0 problem...

Comment: No luck with that.  `<staticContent><remove fileExtension=".xml"/><mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="text/html"/></staticContent>` did not stop the error, nor did the `<staticContent><clear /></staticContent>` that I had previously.

Comment: @erdomke You could try this [config setting](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Managing%20static%20content#letting-iis-handle-static-content) to stop Nancy from processing .xml files.

Comment: @erdomke Also at the bottom of (this page)[https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/View-engines) is this sentence. `As part of the new [Content Negotiation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Content%20Negotiation) features in 0.12, if Nancy could not find your view, the server will return 406 Not Acceptable instead.` Maybe turn on tracing and see what it's not finding?

Comment: Thanks for the additional help.  Unfortunately, I don't think that either of the suggestions are the answer.  (1) I actually do want Nancy to process this request and want to bypass whatever IIS is trying to do for me. (2) I added a screenshot to the answer which shows that this is an IIS error and not a Nancy error.  I also am not currently using Content Negotiation.